# How can I pass argument stored on a variable to WGET

Tags: bash, wget, variable-substitution

I'm writing a bash script that extensively uses wget. To define all common parameters in one place I store them on variables. Here's a piece of code:

```
useragent='--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"'
cookies_file="/tmp/wget-cookies.txt"
save_cookies_cmd="--save-cookies $cookies_file --keep-session-cookies"
load_cookies_cmd="--load-cookies $cookies_file --keep-session-cookies"

function mywget {
    log "#!!!!!!!!!# WGET #!!!!!!!!!# wget $quiet $useragent $load_cookies_cmd $@"  
    wget $useragent $load_cookies_cmd "$@"
}
```

Saddly isn't working. Somehow I'm missing the right way to store parameters on variables $useragent, $save_cookies_cmd, $load_cookies_cmd and caling wget passing these vars as parameters.

I want the result commandline as this:

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0" --load-cookies /tmp/wget-cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies http://mysite.local/myfile.php
```

---

**EDIT:** My final solution:

In the end my script is correctly working with this:

```
useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
useragent_cmd="--user-agent=$useragent"
cookies_file="/tmp/wget-cookies.txt"
save_cookies_cmd="--save-cookies $cookies_file --keep-session-cookies"
load_cookies_cmd="--load-cookies $cookies_file --keep-session-cookies"

function mywget {
    log "#!!!!!!!!!# WGET #!!!!!!!!!# wget $load_cookies_cmd $useragent_cmd $@"  
    wget $load_cookies_cmd "$useragent_cmd" "$@"
}
```

Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

```
user_agent='--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"'
cookies_file="/tmp/wget-cookies.txt"
save_cookies_opts=( --save-cookies "$cookies_file" --keep-session-cookies )
load_cookies_opts=( --load-cookies "$cookies_file" --keep-session-cookies )

function mywget {
    log "#!!!!!!!!!# WGET #!!!!!!!!!# wget $quiet $useragent $load_cookies_cmd $@"
    wget "$user_agent" "${load_cookies_opts[@]}" "$@"
}
```

Note that in the wget call , `"$user_agent"` is quoted. This is crucial.

Comment: Clever using the array. Thanks for your response. It certainly will help me in understanding better bash script.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the order of expansions (see EXPANSION in `man bash` for details). Double quotes inside a variable do not work as double quotes when the variable is expanded:

```
$ a='1 "2 3" 4' ; for b in $a ; do echo $b ; done
1
"2
3"
4
```

Note that using "$b" does not help you.

Use arrays, so you can let bash do the hard work and you can forget about quoting and escaping:

```
$ a=(1 '2 3' 4) ; for b in "${a[@]}" ; do echo $b ; done
1
2 3
4
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm kind of novice in bash script and these tricks will always help me from now on.

Answer (score 3):

```
    mywget() ( echo log "wget $quiet \
                         userstring=${userstring:-unset} \
                         cookies=${cookies:-no} $@"
            echo wget ${userstring:+--useragent="$userstring"} \
                    ${cookies:+--${cookies}-cookies \
                    "$cookies_file" --keep-session-cookies} "$@"
    ) <<-PARAMS
            ${DQ=$(printf \\042)}
            ${NL=
}
            ${userstring="${DQ}Mozilla/5.0 \
                (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) \
                Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0${DQ}"}
            ${cookies_file="/tmp/wget-cookies.txt"}
            ${cookies=save}
    PARAMS
```

Please forgive me, but I've taken the liberty of *`parameterizing`* your function. Because the values in *`PARAMS`* will *only* set an unset variable, you can override their values very easily - it allows you to set sane defaults and yet still change values per function call as you like. For instance, in the above function, I've set all values to *`echo`* and here's the output when run as is:

```
log wget  userstring="Mozilla/5.0 \
    (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) \
    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0" \
    cookies=save
wget --useragent="Mozilla/5.0 \
    (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) \
    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0" \
    --save-cookies /tmp/wget-cookies.txt \
    --keep-session-cookies
```

But if I set *`"$userstring"`* to *`NULL`*:

```
    userstring= mywget
log wget  userstring=unset cookies=save
wget --save-cookies /tmp/wget-cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies
```

Or:

```
    cookies=load cookies_file=/some/other/cookie.file mywget
log wget  userstring="Mozilla/5.0 \
    (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) \
    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0" \
    cookies=load
wget --useragent="Mozilla/5.0 \
    (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) \
    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0" \
    --load-cookies /some/other/cookie.file \
    --keep-session-cookies
```

Or:

```
    cookies= userstring= mywget
log wget  userstring=unset cookies=no
wget
```

I've written more on *`parameter expansion`* [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/how-to-defer-variable-expansion/120142#120142) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/trapping-errors-in-command-substitution-using-o-errtrace-ie-set-e/120008#120008).