# Using "${a:-b}" for variable assignment in scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, variable

I have been looking at a few scripts other people wrote (specifically Red Hat), and a lot of their variables are assigned using the following notation
`VARIABLE1="${VARIABLE1:-some_val}"`
or some expand other variables
`` VARIABLE2="${VARIABLE2:-`echo $VARIABLE1`}" ``

What is the point of using this notation instead of just declaring the values directly (e.g., `VARIABLE1=some_val`)?

Are there benefits to this notation or possible errors that would be prevented?

Does the `:-` have specific meaning in this context?

Comment: Crazy how after 20 years using the shell I have never come to see this notation yet!

Answer (score 1066, accepted):

This technique allows for a variable to be assigned a value if another variable is either empty or is undefined. **NOTE:** This "other variable" can be the same or another variable.

*excerpt*

```
${parameter:-word}
    If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. 
    Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
```

**NOTE:** This form also works, `${parameter-word}`. According to [the Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), for all such expansions:

> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests for both *parameter*’s existence and that its value is not null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.

If you'd like to see a full list of all forms of parameter expansion available within Bash then I highly suggest you take a look at this topic in the Bash Hacker's wiki titled: "[Parameter expansion](https://web.archive.org/web/20200309072646/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)".

#### Examples

##### *variable doesn't exist*

```
$ echo "$VAR1"

$ VAR1="${VAR1:-default value}"
$ echo "$VAR1"
default value
```

##### *variable exists*

```
$ VAR1="has value"
$ echo "$VAR1"
has value

$ VAR1="${VAR1:-default value}"
$ echo "$VAR1"
has value
```

The same thing can be done by evaluating other variables, or running commands within the default value portion of the notation.

```
$ VAR2="has another value"
$ echo "$VAR2"
has another value
$ echo "$VAR1"

$

$ VAR1="${VAR1:-$VAR2}"
$ echo "$VAR1"
has another value
```

#### More Examples

You can also use a slightly different notation where it's just `VARX=${VARX-<def. value>}`.

```
$ echo "${VAR1-0}"
has another value
$ echo "${VAR2-0}"
has another value
$ echo "${VAR3-0}"
0
```

In the above `$VAR1` & `$VAR2` were already defined with the string "has another value" but `$VAR3` was undefined, so the default value was used instead, `0`.

#### Another Example

```
$ VARX="${VAR3-0}"
$ echo "$VARX"
0
```

#### Checking and assigning using `:=` notation

Lastly I'll mention the handy operator, `:=`. This will do a check and assign a value if the variable under test is empty or undefined.

#### Example

Notice that `$VAR1` is now set. The operator `:=` did the test and the assignment in a single operation.

```
$ unset VAR1
$ echo "$VAR1"

$ echo "${VAR1:=default}"
default
$ echo "$VAR1"
default
```

However if the value is set prior, then it's left alone.

```
$ VAR1="some value"
$ echo "${VAR1:=default}"
some value
$ echo "$VAR1"
some value
```

#### Handy Dandy Reference Table

|  | Parameter set and not null | Parameter set but null | Parameter unset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `${parameter:-word}` | substitute *parameter* | substitute *word* | substitute *word* |
| `${parameter-word}` | substitute *parameter* | substitute *null* | substitute *word* |
| `${parameter:=word}` | substitute *parameter* | assign *word* | assign *word* |
| `${parameter=word}` | substitute *parameter* | substitute *null* | assign *word* |
| `${parameter:?word}` | substitute *parameter* | error, exit | error, exit |
| `${parameter?word}` | substitute *parameter* | substitute *null* | error, exit |
| `${parameter:+word}` | substitute *word* | substitute *null* | substitute *null* |
| `${parameter+word}` | substitute *word* | substitute *word* | substitute *null* |

([Screenshot of source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Fp8.png))

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657434/bash-parameter-expansion-substituted-versus-assigned) makes the difference between *assignment* and *substitution* explicit: Assignment sets a value for the variable whereas substitution doesn't.

#### References

- [Parameter Expansions - Bash Hackers Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20200309072646/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)
- [10.2. Parameter Substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)
- [Bash Parameter Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Using `echo "${FOO:=default}"` is great if you actually want the `echo`. But if you don't, then try the `:` built-in ... `: ${FOO:=default}`  Your `$FOO` is set to `default` as above (i.e., if not already set). But there's no echoing of `$FOO` in the process.

Comment: It seems this does not work for positional parameters, like in: `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${4:='.'}`. The case is, within a script, to use $4 as an output directory, if it has been given when executing the script (`sh script.sh one two three /some/output/directory`) or use '.' instead if it hasn't (`sh script.sh one two three`). How can this be done?

Comment: Ok, found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24405606/1172302. Using the `${4:-$VAR}` will work.

Comment: It also allows users to provide their own value for a given variable.  This can be very useful when working around issues not foreseen at the time the script was written.

Comment: `wiki.bash-hackers.org` is currently down: https://github.com/rawiriblundell/wiki.bash-hackers.org

Comment: @PerLundberg - ty I've updated it w/ archive.org - https://web.archive.org/web/20200309072646/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.

Answer (score 21):

@slm has already included the [POSIX docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) - which are very helpful - but they don't really expand on how these parameters can be combined to affect one another. There is not yet any mention here of this form:

```
${var?if unset parent shell dies and this message is output to stderr}
```

This is an excerpt from [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/trapping-errors-in-command-substitution-using-o-errtrace-ie-set-e/120008#120008) of mine, and I think it demonstrates very well how these work:

```
    sh <<-\CMD
    _input_fn() { set -- "$@" #redundant
            echo ${*?WHERES MY DATA?}
            #echo is not necessary though
            shift #sure hope we have more than $1 parameter
            : ${*?WHERES MY DATA?} #: do nothing, gracefully
    }
    _input_fn heres some stuff
    _input_fn one #here
    # shell dies - third try doesnt run
    _input_fn you there?
    # END
    CMD
heres some stuff
one
sh: line :5 *: WHERES MY DATA?
```

Another example from [same](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/trapping-errors-in-command-substitution-using-o-errtrace-ie-set-e/120008#120008):

```
    sh <<-\CMD
    N= #N is NULL
    _test=$N #_test is also NULL and
    v="something you would rather do without"    
    ( #this subshell dies
        echo "v is ${v+set}: and its value is ${v:+not NULL}"
        echo "So this ${_test:-"\$_test:="} will equal ${_test:="$v"}"
        ${_test:+${N:?so you test for it with a little nesting}}
        echo "sure wish we could do some other things"
    )
    ( #this subshell does some other things 
        unset v #to ensure it is definitely unset
        echo "But here v is ${v-unset}: ${v:+you certainly wont see this}"
        echo "So this ${_test:-"\$_test:="} will equal NULL ${_test:="$v"}"
        ${_test:+${N:?is never substituted}}
        echo "so now we can do some other things" 
    )
    #and even though we set _test and unset v in the subshell
    echo "_test is still ${_test:-"NULL"} and ${v:+"v is still $v"}"
    # END
    CMD
v is set: and its value is not NULL
So this $_test:= will equal something you would rather do without
sh: line 7: N: so you test for it with a little nesting
But here v is unset:
So this $_test:= will equal NULL
so now we can do some other things
_test is still NULL and v is still something you would rather do without
```

The above example takes advantage of all 4 forms of POSIX parameter substitution and their various *`:colon null`* or *`not null`* tests. There is more information in the link above, and [here it is again](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Another thing that people often don't consider about `${parameter:+expansion}` is how very useful it can be in a here-document. Here's another excerpt from a [different answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120142/52934):

#### TOP

Here you'll set some defaults and prepare to print them when called...

```
#!/bin/sh
    _top_of_script_pr() ( 
        IFS="$nl" ; set -f #only split at newlines and don't expand paths
        printf %s\\n ${strings}
    ) 3<<-TEMPLATES
        ${nl=
}
        ${PLACE:="your mother's house"}
        ${EVENT:="the unspeakable."}
        ${ACTION:="heroin"}
        ${RESULT:="succeed."}
        ${strings:="
            I went to ${PLACE} and saw ${EVENT}
            If you do ${ACTION} you will ${RESULT}
        "}
    #END
    TEMPLATES
```

#### MIDDLE

This is where you define other functions to call on your print function based on their results...

```
    EVENT="Disney on Ice."
    _more_important_function() { #...some logic...
        [ $((1+one)) -ne 2 ] && ACTION="remedial mathematics"
            _top_of_script_pr
    }
    _less_important_function() { #...more logic...
        one=2
        : "${ACTION:="calligraphy"}"
        _top_of_script_pr
    }
```

#### BOTTOM

You've got it all setup now, so here's where you'll execute and pull your results.

```
    _less_important_function
    : "${PLACE:="the cemetery"}" 
    _more_important_function
    : "${RESULT:="regret it."}" 
    _less_important_function
```

#### RESULTS

I'll go into why in a moment, but running the above produces the following results:

> *`_less_important_function()'s`* first run:
>
> > I went to your mother's house and saw *Disney on Ice.*
> >
> > If you do *calligraphy* you will succeed.
>
> then *`_more_important_function():`*
>
> > I went to the *cemetery* and saw Disney on Ice.
> >
> > If you do *remedial mathematics* you will succeed.
>
> *`_less_important_function()`* again:
>
> > I went to the cemetery and saw Disney on Ice.
> >
> > If you do remedial mathematics you will *regret it.*

#### HOW IT WORKS:

The key feature here is the concept of *`conditional ${parameter} expansion.`* You can set a variable to a value only if it is unset or null using the form:

> > *`${var_name`**:=**`desired_value}`*

If instead you wish to set only an unset variable, you would omit the *`:colon`* and null values would remain as is.

#### ON SCOPE:

You might notice that in the above example *`$PLACE`* and *`$RESULT`* get changed when set via *`parameter expansion`* even though *`_top_of_script_pr()`* has already been called, presumably setting them when it's run. The reason this works is that *`_top_of_script_pr()`* is a *`( subshelled )`* function - I enclosed it in *`parens`* rather than the *`{ curly braces }`* used for the others. Because it is called in a subshell, every variable it sets is *`locally scoped`* and as it returns to its parent shell those values disappear.

But when *`_more_important_function()`* sets *`$ACTION`* it is *`globally scoped`* so it affects *`_less_important_function()'s`* second evaluation of *`$ACTION`* because *`_less_important_function()`* sets *`$ACTION`* only via *`${parameter:=expansion}.`*

Answer (score 14):

Personal experience.

I use this format sometimes in my scripts to do ad-hoc over-riding of values, e.g. if I have:

```
$ cat script.sh
SOMETHING="${SOMETHING:-something}"; echo "$SOMETHING";
```

I can run:

```
$ env SOMETHING="something other than the default value" ./script.sh`
```

without having to change the original default value of `SOMETHING`.

Comment: Fancy way of passing/overriding variables to/in a script :)

Answer (score -1):

An interesting way of getting a single command-line parameter uses the $1, $2 ... scheme.

```
echo "$1 $2 $3"
Two=$(2:-'default2')
echo "Second parameter: $Two"
```

Called with parameters: Won too tree

Result: Second parameter: too

Called with parameters: Five!

Result: Second parameter: default2