# Write a shell script that takes in a variable from the terminal? (~$ command variable)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a shell script that takes in a time (in minutes) and opens an online egg timer set for that amount.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Opens http://e.ggtimer.com/TIMEmin where TIME = number of minutes
TIME=5
xdg-open http://e.ggtimer.com/"$TIME"min
```

When I run the above script it opens the web page http://e.ggtimer.com/5min
I would like to set the time from the terminal.
For example:

```
eggtimer 10
```

Would open http://e.ggtimer.com/10min

Thank you!

Comment: The first command line argument is `$1` so `TIME=$1` or just put `$1` in your URL.

Comment: @JosephR. Even if it seems too simple to you: Make that an answer so that it can be accepted and the question get marked done.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Seems slm already took care of that :)

Comment: I swear I didn't even see your comment, I was already thinking of my `${VAR:-defaultval}` post when I wrote it, just saw the commentary now.

Comment: @slm No worries. My previous comment was sincere, not passive aggressive :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the following feature of Bash variables where they're used if they have a value otherwise a default value is used instead you can code up your example like so:

```
$ more etimer.bash 
#!/bin/bash
#Opens http://e.ggtimer.com/TIMEmin where TIME = number of minutes
TIME=${1:-5}
xdg-open http://e.ggtimer.com/"$TIME"min
```

This will use an argument that's passed into `etimer.bash` if one is provided, otherwise will use 5 minutes.

#### Examples

```
$ ./etimer.bash
```

Results in this URL: http://e.ggtimer.com/5min

```
$ ./etimer.bash 10
```

Results in this URL: http://e.ggtimer.com/10min

#### References

- [Using "${a:-b}" for variable assignment in scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts/122848#122848)