# Shortest way to extract last 3 characters of base (minus suffix) filename

Tags: shell-script, filenames

I'm trying to set a variable in an sh script to the last 3 characters of the base name of a file (by base name I mean without the path *and* without the suffix). I've succeeded in doing this but, purely out of curiosity, I'm wondering if there is a shorter, single command I can use. Originally I had a one-liner with `awk`, but it was rather long. Currently I have this two-line script (assuming a complete filename is in `$1`):

```
filebase=`basename "$1"`
lastpart=`echo -n ${filebase%.*} | tail -c3`
```

So for example, *"/path/to/somefile.txt"* ends up with *"ile"* in `$lastpart`.

Can I somehow combine `basename` and the bit to strip the suffix into a single command, and is there a way to send it to `tail` (or something else I can use) without using a pipe? The suffix is unknown so I can't base it as a parameter to `basename`.

The main goal isn't actually so much to be as short as possible, as to be as readable at a glance as possible. The actual context of all of this is [this question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/772181/matching-files-to-folders/772190#772190), where I'm trying to come up with a reasonably simple answer.

Comment: How would you deal with a file like `file.one.two.three`? Would you want `ile` or `two`?

Comment: @terdon `two` would work; the extension on that would be `.three` I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a typical job for `expr`:

```
$ file=/path/to/abcdef.txt
$ expr "/$file" : '.*\([^/.]\{3\}\)\.[^/.]*$'
def
```

If you know your file names have the expected format (contains one and only one dot and at least 3 characters before the dot), that can be simplified to:

```
expr "/$file" : '.*\(.\{3\}\)\.'
```

Note that the exit status will be non-zero if there's no match, but also if the matched part is a number that resolves to 0. (like for `a000.txt` or `a-00.txt`)

With `zsh`:

```
file=/path/to/abcdef.txt
lastpart=${${file:t:r}[-3,-1]}
```

(`:t` for *tail* (basename), `:r` for *rest* (with extension removed)).

Comment: Nice. `expr` is another one I need to get familiar with. I *really* like the `zsh` solutions in general (I was just reading about its support for nested substitutions on the left side of a `${}` yesterday too and wishing `sh` had the same), it's just a bummer that it isn't always present by default.

Comment: @JasonC - you'll get no hard feelings from me if you change your accepted answer - this is a better one, I think.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks; your answer taught me a lot too. I am going to change this because this one is short and succinct; but let's blame SE for not giving us runner-ups.

Comment: @JasonC - the information matters most. Make the best of it as accessible as you can - thats the whole point of the system anyway. If rep bought food i might get upset, but more often *(than never)* info brings home the bacon

Comment: @mikeserv "Request: Exchange rep for bacon"; look out meta here I come.

Comment: @mikerserv, yours is POSIX, uses builtins only and doesn't fork any process. Not using command substitution also means you avoid problems with trailing newlines, so it's a good answer too.

Comment: Well, gracias, Stephane. But are you saying `expr` isn't POSIX? I thought for sure it was! I take it all back. But anyway, I've often noticed good answers that came a little later don't get noticed so well as they should after an answer has been accepted. Mine's already got 7 votes - that's good enough. This'll get seen now. That's all I cared about.

Comment: @mikeserv, I didn't mean to imply `expr` was _not_ POSIX. It certainly is. It's rarely built-in though.

Answer (score 14):

```
var=123456
echo "${var#"${var%???}"}"

###OUTPUT###

456
```

That first removes the last three characters from `$var` then removes from `$var` the results of that removal - which returns the last three characters of `$var`.  Here are some examples more specifically aimed at demonstrating how you might do such a thing:

```
touch file.txt
path=${PWD}/file.txt
echo "$path"

/tmp/file.txt

base=${path##*/}
exten=${base#"${base%???}"}
base=${base%."$exten"}
{ 
    echo "$base" 
    echo "$exten" 
    echo "${base}.${exten}" 
    echo "$path"
}

file
txt
file.txt
/tmp/file.txt
```

You don't have to spread this all out through so many commands. You can compact this:

```
{
    base=${path##*/} exten= 
    printf %s\\n "${base%.*}" "${exten:=${base#"${base%???}"}}" "$base" "$path"
    echo "$exten"
}

file 
txt 
file.txt 
/tmp/file.txt
txt
```

Combining `$IFS` with `set`ting shell parameters can also be a very effective means of parsing and drilling through shell variables:

```
(IFS=. ; set -f; set -- ${path##*/}; printf %s "${1#"${1%???}"}")
```

That will get you only the three characters immediately preceding the first period following the last `/` in `$path`. If you want to retrieve only the first three characters immediately preceding the last `.` in `$path` *(for instance, if there is a possibility of more than one `.` in filename)*:

```
(IFS=.; set -f; set -- ${path##*/}; ${3+shift $(($#-2))}; printf %s "${1#"${1%???}"}")
```

In both cases you can do:

```
newvar=$(IFS...)
```

And...

```
(IFS...;printf %s "$2")
```

...will print what follows the `.`

If you don't mind using an external program you can do:

```
printf %s "${path##*/}" | sed 's/.*\(...\)\..*/\1/'
```

If there is a chance of a `\n`ewline character in the filename *(not applicable for the native shell solutions - they all handle that anyway)*:

```
printf %s "${path##*/}" | sed 'H;$!d;g;s/.*\(...\)\..*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks; this gives me something to think about, although it doesn't quite work. With this, `/path/to/123456.txt` becomes `txt`, but I need to get the bit before the extension (`456`). I'll have to find out how to combine it with the `%.*` thing, which is also kind of new to me.

Comment: It is, thanks. I've also found [documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html). But to get the last 3 characters from `$base` there, the best I could do was the three-line `name=${var##*/} ; base=${name%%.*} ; lastpart=${base#${base%???}}`. On the plus side it's pure bash, but it's still 3 lines. (In your example of "/tmp/file.txt" I'd need "ile" rather than "file".) I did just learn a lot about parameter substitution; I had no idea it could do that... pretty handy. I do find it very readable, as well, personally.

Comment: @JasonC - this is fully portable behavior - it is not bash specific. I recommend reading [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

Comment: Well, I guess, I can use `%` instead of `%%` to remove the suffix, and I don't actually need to strip the path, so I can get a nicer, two line `noextn=${var%.*} ; lastpart=${noextn#${noextn%???}}`.

Comment: @JasonC - yes, that looks like it would work. It will break if there is `$IFS` in `${noextn}` and you do not quote the expansion. So, this is safer: `lastpart=${noextn#"${noextn%???}"}`

Comment: @JasonC - last, if you found the above helpful, you might want to look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts/122892#122892). It deals with other forms of parameter expansion and the other answers to that question are really good too. And there are links to two other answers on the same subject within. If you want.

Comment: @mikeserv: Your solution will fail when suffix is not 3 characters.

Comment: @Gnouc - i know. But he asked for the last three characters. In fact he doesnt want the extension, if you look at his comments from `file.txt` he wants `ile`.

Comment: @Gnouc - I guess another way could be `IFS=/. ; set -- $path ; unset IFS ; shift $((${#}-2)) ; printf %s\\n "${1#"${1%???}"}" "$2"`

Comment: @mikeserv: cool! But I like to use `perl` with parsing text like this, see my answer.

Comment: @mikeserv He clarified that he wanted the last three characters of the filename _without_ the suffix. Maybe you should modify your answer to include the solution from your last comment.

Comment: @Dubu - I think I might. But the answer was more about demonstrating how. Still, it's a very good idea.

Comment: The quotes in `lastpart=${noextn#"${noextn%???}"}` are not about `IFS`, it's to prevent `${noextn%???}` from being taken as a pattern.

Comment: Thanks, @StephaneChazelas. Ive never thought about it like that before - just had enough bad experiences nesting expansions to always quote those. But, to clarify - you mean the expansion of `${...}` right? Like  in the cases`p='???' ; ${strip%$p}` and `${strip%"$p"}` the first drops last three characters whereas second drops last three characters if theyre '?'... right? It will always expand, right?

Comment: yes. It's `${var#$pattern}` or `${var#"$string"}`. Same goes for `case $x in $pattern) "$string")` or `[[ $x = $pattern ]]/[[ $x = "$string" ]]` in ksh or bash.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use `perl`:

```
lastpart=$(
    perl -e 'print substr((split(/\.[^.]*$/,shift))[0], -3, 3)
            ' -- "$(basename -- "$1")"
)
```

Comment: that is cool. got ny vote.

Comment: A bit more concise: `perl -e 'shift =~ /(.{3})\.[^.]*$/ && print $1' $filename`. An additional `basename` would be needed if the filename might contain no suffix but some directory in the path does.

Comment: @Dubu: Your solution always fails if filename has no suffix.

Comment: @Gnouc This was by intent. But you're right, this could be wrong depending on the purpose. Alternative: `perl -e 'shift =~ m#(.{3})(?:\.[^./]*)?$# && print $1' $filename`

Answer (score 2):

`sed` works for this:

```
[user@host ~]$ echo one.two.txt | sed -r 's|(.*)\..*$|\1|;s|.*(...)$|\1|'
two
```

Or

```
[user@host ~]$ sed -r 's|(.*)\..*$|\1|;s|.*(...)$|\1|' <<<one.two.txt
two
```

If your `sed` doesn't support `-r`, just replace the instances of `()` with `\(` and `\)`, and then `-r` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

If perl is available, I find it can be more readable than other solutions, specifically because its regex language is more expressive and it has the `/x` modifier, which allows for writing clearer regexs:

```
perl -e 'print $1 if shift =~ m{ ( [^/]{3} ) [.] [^./]* \z }x' -- "$file"
```

This prints nothing if there is no such match (if the basename has no extension or if the root before the extension is too short).  Depending on your requirements, you can adjust the regex.  This regex enforces the constraints:

1. It matches the 3 characters before the final extension (the part after and including the last dot).  These 3 characters can contain a dot.
2. The extension can be empty (except for the dot).
3. The matched part and the extension must be part of the basename (the part after the last slash).

Using this in a command substitution has the normal issues with removing too many trailing newlines, a problem which also affects Stéphane's answer.  It can be dealt with in both cases, but is a little easier here:

```
lastpart=$(
  perl -e 'print "$1x" if shift =~ m{ ( [^/]{3} ) [.] [^./]* \z }x' -- "$file"
)
lastpart=${lastpart%x}  # allow for possible trailing newline
```

Answer (score 0):

Python2.7

```
$ echo /path/to/somefile.txt | python -c "import sys, os; print '.'.join(os.path.basename(sys.stdin.read()).split('.')[:-1])[-3:]"
ile

$ echo file.one.two.three | python -c "import sys, os; print '.'.join(os.path.basename(sys.stdin.read()).split('.')[:-1])[-3:]"
two
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this bash function, pathStr(), will do what you are looking for.

It doesn't require awk, sed, grep, perl or expr. It uses only bash builtins so it's quite fast.

I've also included the dependent argsNumber and isOption functions but their functionalities could be easily incorporated into pathStr.

The dependent function ifHelpShow is not included as it has numerous subdependencies for outputting the help text either on the terminal commandline or to a GUI dialog box via [YAD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/). The help text passed to it is included for documentation. Advise if you would like ifHelpShow and its dependents.

```
function  pathStr () {
  ifHelpShow "$1" 'pathStr --OPTION FILENAME
    Given FILENAME, pathStr echos the segment chosen by --OPTION of the
    "absolute-logical" pathname. Only one segment can be retrieved at a time and
    only the FILENAME string is parsed. The filesystem is never accessed, except
    to get the current directory in order to build an absolute path from a relative
    path. Thus, this function may be used on a FILENAME that does not yet exist.
    Path characteristics:
        File paths are "absolute" or "relative", and "logical" or "physical".
        If current directory is "/root", then for "bashtool" in the "sbin" subdirectory ...
            Absolute path:  /root/sbin/bashtool
            Relative path:  sbin/bashtool
        If "/root/sbin" is a symlink to "/initrd/mnt/dev_save/share/sbin", then ...
            Logical  path:  /root/sbin/bashtool
            Physical path:  /initrd/mnt/dev_save/share/sbin/bashtool
                (aka: the "canonical" path)
    Options:
        --path  Absolute-logical path including filename with extension(s)
                  ~/sbin/file.name.ext:     /root/sbin/file.name.ext
        --dir   Absolute-logical path of directory containing FILENAME (which can be a directory).
                  ~/sbin/file.name.ext:     /root/sbin
        --file  Filename only, including extension(s).
                  ~/sbin/file.name.ext:     file.name.ext
        --base  Filename only, up to last dot(.).
                  ~/sbin/file.name.ext:     file.name
        --ext   Filename after last dot(.).
                  ~/sbin/file.name.ext:     ext
    Todo:
        Optimize by using a regex to match --options so getting argument only done once.
    Revised:
        20131231  docsalvage'  && return
  #
  local _option="$1"
  local _optarg="$2"
  local _cwd="$(pwd)"
  local _fullpath=
  local _tmp1=
  local _tmp2=
  #
  # validate there are 2 args and first is an --option
  [[ $(argsNumber "$@") != 2 ]]                        && return 1
  ! isOption "$@"                                      && return 1
  #
  # determine full path of _optarg given
  if [[ ${_optarg:0:1} == "/" ]]
  then
    _fullpath="$_optarg"
  else
    _fullpath="$_cwd/$_optarg"
  fi
  #
  case "$_option" in
   --path)  echo "$_fullpath"                            ; return 0;;
    --dir)  echo "${_fullpath%/*}"                       ; return 0;;
   --file)  echo "${_fullpath##*/}"                      ; return 0;;
   --base)  _tmp1="${_fullpath##*/}"; echo "${_tmp1%.*}" ; return 0;;
    --ext)  _tmp1="${_fullpath##*/}";
            _tmp2="${_tmp1##*.}";
            [[ "$_tmp2" != "$_tmp1" ]]  && { echo "$_tmp2"; }
            return 0;;
  esac
  return 1
}

function argsNumber () {
  ifHelpShow "$1" 'argsNumber "$@"
  Echos number of arguments.
  Wrapper for "$#" or "${#@}" which are equivalent.
  Verified by testing on bash 4.1.0(1):
      20140627 docsalvage
  Replaces:
      argsCount
  Revised:
      20140627 docsalvage'  && return
  #
  echo "$#"
  return 0
}

function isOption () {
  # isOption "$@"
  # Return true (0) if argument has 1 or more leading hyphens.
  # Example:
  #     isOption "$@"  && ...
  # Note:
  #   Cannot use ifHelpShow() here since cannot distinguish 'isOption --help'
  #   from 'isOption "$@"' where first argument in "$@" is '--help'
  # Revised:
  #     20140117 docsalvage
  # 
  # support both short and long options
  [[ "${1:0:1}" == "-" ]]  && return 0
  return 1
}
```

**RESOURCES**

- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207168/a-semantics-for-bash-scripts/23208014#23208014

Comment: I don't understand - it's already been demoed here how to do similar fully portably - without `bash`isms - seemingly simpler than this. Also, what is `${#@}`?

Comment: This just packages the functionality into a reusable function. re:${#@}... Manipulating arrays and their elements requires the full variable notation ${}. $@ is the 'array' of arguments. ${#@} is the bash syntax for the number of arguments.

Comment: No, `$#` is the syntax for the number of arguments, and it is also used elsewhere here.

Comment: You are right that "$#" is the widely documented systax for "number of arguments." However, I've just reverified that "${#@}" is equivalent. I wound up with that after experimenting with the differences and similarities between positional arguments and arrays. The later comes from the array syntax which apparently is a synonym for the shorter, simpler "$#" syntax. I've altered and documented argsNumber() to use "$#". Thanks!

Comment: `${#@}` is not equivalent in most cases - the POSIX spec states the results of any parameter expansions on either `$@` or `$*` are unspecified, unfortunately. It may work in `bash` but that is not a reliable feature, I guess is what I'm trying to say.,

Comment: Added bash version to internal help for function argsNumber.