# What does /lib/lsb/init-functions do?

Tags: debian, shell-script

I need to understand the meaning of the following code from `/lib/lsb/init-functions`:

```
 base=${1##*/}
```

Also it would be helpful if it was possible to explain how `pidofproc` function returns the values to `status_of_proc`.

EDIT:

`pidofproc`

```
pidofproc () {
    local pidfile base status specified pid OPTIND
pidfile=
specified=

OPTIND=1
while getopts p: opt ; do
    case "$opt" in
        p)  pidfile="$OPTARG"
            specified="specified"
    ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "$0: invalid arguments" >&2
    return 4
fi

base=${1##*/}
if [ ! "$specified" ]; then
    pidfile="/var/run/$base.pid"
fi

if [ -n "${pidfile:-}" -a -r "$pidfile" ]; then
    read pid < "$pidfile"
    if [ -n "${pid:-}" ]; then
        if $(kill -0 "${pid:-}" 2> /dev/null); then
            echo "$pid" || true
            return 0
        elif ps "${pid:-}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            echo "$pid" || true
            return 0 # program is running, but not owned by this user
        else
            return 1 # program is dead and /var/run pid file exists
        fi
    fi
fi
if [ -n "$specified" ]; then
    if [ -e "$pidfile" -a ! -r "$pidfile" ]; then
        return 4 # pidfile exists, but unreadable, return unknown
    else
        return 3 # pidfile specified, but contains no PID to test
    fi
fi
if [ -x /bin/pidof ]; then
    status="0"
    /bin/pidof -o %PPID -x $1 || status="$?"
    if [ "$status" = 1 ]; then
        return 3 # program is not running
    fi
    return 0
fi
return 4 # Unable to determine status
}
```

`status_of_proc`

```
status_of_proc () {
    local pidfile daemon name status OPTIND

pidfile=
OPTIND=1
while getopts p: opt ; do
    case "$opt" in
        p)  pidfile="$OPTARG";;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

if [ -n "$pidfile" ]; then
    pidfile="-p $pidfile"
fi
daemon="$1"
name="$2"

status="0"
pidofproc $pidfile $daemon >/dev/null || status="$?"
if [ "$status" = 0 ]; then
    log_success_msg "$name is running"
    return 0
elif [ "$status" = 4 ]; then
    log_failure_msg "could not access PID file for $name"
    return $status
else
    log_failure_msg "$name is not running"
    return $status
fi
}
```

Comment: maybe see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138634/shortest-way-to-extract-last-3-characters-of-base-minus-suffix-filename/138635#138635)... but more directly, that sets the shell variable `$base` to whatever `$1`'s value is after all characters up to the last occurring `/` char is stripped from its head. Can we have copies of `pidofproc` and/or `status_of_proc`?

Comment: @mikeserv: So `base` will contain the filename, it seems. Thankyou

Comment: you're quite welcome. if you're still curious about p&p then please paste in their contents.

Comment: @mikeserv: I have posted the function body. Also I am not very familiar with shell scripting.

Comment: The two functions share the shell environment var `$pidfile` - which is a lockfile, essentially, and they write into, `read` from it. wait, no... status empties that var... just a sec.

Comment: yes. But I cant find any pidfile that is unreadable or that doesnot contain info about pid. So how come it returns any value other than 0?

Comment: @mikeserv Beware that using the term "lockfile" risks sowing confusion.  In the init daemon context, that term is used for this purpose: '"/var/lock/subsys/${lock_file}".  The shell variable $pidfile is used to hold the name of the file that identifies one or more process id numbers associated with the daemon, while the daemon is running.  Name is: /var/run/mydaemon.pid.  Contents is typically just a single number (like 23232) but it can be multiple lines and multiple numbers per line.  (Though, honestly, I don't know what sort of daemon would create such a multi-value pidfile).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here:

```
status="0"
pidofproc $pidfile $daemon >/dev/null || status="$?"
```

So `status_of_proc` calls `pidofproc` which sets `$base`. This variable value is set in the current shell and so its value persists when `pidofproc` returns to `status_of_proc`.

For example:

```
fn1() { unset var; fn2; echo "$var"; }
fn2() { var=set; }
fn1
```

#### OUTPUT

```
set
```

In the following `[` test `]` command `pidofproc` evaluates `$pidfile` and returns based on its results:

```
[ -e "$pidfile" -a ! -r "$pidfile" ]
```

So that translates to:

```
if $pidfile exists and it is not readable
```

The full text is here:

```
if [ -e "$pidfile" -a ! -r "$pidfile" ]; then
        return 4 # pidfile exists, but unreadable, return unknown
    else
        return 3 # pidfile specified, but contains no PID to test
```

Comment: I understood that. But what I would like to know is: in `\var\run\` there is no `.pid` file that is either empty or unreadable. Then how does `procofpid` returns 1,3 or 4? Also for one of the daemons that has a readable pidfile, it returns 4. How will this happen?

Comment: `$pidfile` is set to: `pidfile="/var/run/$base.pid"`

Comment: Yes. I parsed all files in that folder that has `.pid` extension.

Comment: @Anzz - look again maybe? Closer to the mark, maybe? You might get 4 even with the readable `$pidfile` if for some reason the following does not execute correctly: `/bin/pidof -o %PPID -x $1 || status="$?"`

Comment: Sorry for repeated questions. But can you explain what that line does?

Comment: ok.. Now the script seems somewhat readable for me. :)

Comment: @Anzz - first you wanna find out if you have the command - do `hash pidof`. I almost never use it and so am not clear on what the `-o` option does, but I assume it has something to do with the PPID. Still, that is not a shell var - that must be some `pidof` syntax. Anyway, that calls `pidof` - probably to get the PID of whatever is in "$1". If that command is successful it does not set `$status` to 1.

Comment: ok..Thankyou. Now let me check it again with all these info. Thanks a lot..