# Substituting default value ('0') for null parameter

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a query that returns some numbers from the db and I'm trying to put that into a file to send out. However, some of the values come back as null and I'm trying to substitute '0' in for some calculations in those cases. The only time I can get it to '0' it also does that for variables that have actual values. Below is my code and output. What am I doing wrong? (Very new to bash/Linux.)

```
I use these commands:           and I get this output:
echo ${awb-$defaultbase}            NULL
echo ${gachurn-$defaultbase}        2 - 
echo ${awb+$defaultbase}            0
echo ${gachurn+$defaultbase}        0 - 
echo ${awb:-$defaultbase}           NULL
echo ${gachurn:-$defaultbase}       2 - 
echo ${awb:+$defaultbase}           0
echo ${gachurn:+$defaultbase}       0 - 
echo $awb                           NULL
echo $gachurn                       2
```

I want the first value to be 0 and the second to be 2.

Comment: So I just realized that the value of awb may just be the text "NULL" and not actually null. That seems like the only explanation to me as to why I get what I get. Also, this thread has been helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts/122848#122848

Comment: Yep. That was it. I had to use if statements but if there is a better way let me know. if [ "$gachurn" == NULL ]; then gachurn=0; fi

Answer (score 1):

`NULL`, given back from the database, is a string of four characters and will not be interpreted as the "null string" (empty string) by the shell.

To check whether `$awb` is `NULL` and replace it with zero, you may for example do

```
[ "$awb" = 'NULL' ] && awb=0
```

This is slightly shorter to write than

```
if [ "$awb" = 'NULL' ]; then
    awb=0
fi
```

In `bash`, you may also do a string substitution, as [G-Man suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242907/116858):

```
awb=${awb/NULL/0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"${awb/NULL/0}"`, which does a simple search and replace. 
Beware that this will find and replace substrings, so,
if the value of the variable is `NULL_and_VOID`, you will get `0_and_VOID`.

Also note that you should always quote all references to shell variables
(as shown above) unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.