# Does tcsh have an equivalent for “${a:-b}” for default variable assignment like Bash?

Tags: alias, tcsh, variable-substitution

I want to do this in one line because I want to use it in my aliases. Can I do this similarly in tcsh ? [Using “${a:-b}” for variable assignment in scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122848/137196)

There are some ways of doing it here but with if-else, can I do it in one line?
http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt

eg, how do I make first argument an special string if it is not given ?

```
setenv SVN_URL "http://svn-repo"
alias svn-log  'svn log \:!1'
```

I want it to be like this, if nothing added, then don't add anything (svn will use current path . )

```
svn-log

svn-log http://svn-repo
```

when I add something as first argument

```
svn-log  http://svn-repo/path-to-something
```

runs

```
svn-log  http://svn-repo/path-to-something
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but optional arguments are possible via history substitution in an alias definition.

```
> alias blatt 'echo \!:1*'
> blatt

> blatt blah
blah
>
```