# Compound Docker Entrypoint?

Tags: docker, duplicity

I need to backup a docker volume to a specific directory within another docker volume using Duplicity.  So I need to run a command like this within the container performing the backup:

```
mkdir -p /backup/$backup-label
duplicity /target file:///backup/$backup-label
```

So I have created a docker image containing duplicity so I can run the above command with mapping the volume to be backed up to `/target` and the volume that stores the backup to `/backup`.

So my question is how to I pass $backup-label to the `run` command and how do I create the Entrypoint so that it makes sure that the correct directory structure exists prior to running duplicity as indicated above?

TIA,
Ole

P.S.
If I could run the container like this:

```
ole@MKI:~$ docker run --rm -it -v data-volume:/target -v backup-volume/label-for-backup:/backup duplicity-backup-image
```

That would solve it.  But apparently docker does not allow the mapping of subdirectories within volumes.  When I try I get the following message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create backup-volume/label-for-backup: "backup-volume/label-for-backup" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed.
```

Comment: I ended up rewording this question a bit on stackoverflow and received an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324541/referencing-a-dynamic-argument-in-the-docker-entrypoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution is to use a shell script as `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`.

If you want to pass variables into the script, you can use -e to pass any environment variables to the script: `docker run -e backup-label=somelabel`. This option has the advantage that you can configure various areas without interpreting parameters. I suggest to also look into the [`${variable:-}` syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122848/202418).

In your case: `docker run --rm -e backup-label=somelabel -it -v data-volume:/target -v backup-volume/label-for-backup:/backup duplicity-backup-image`

The shell script (make sure it's executable):

```
#!/bin/sh 
mkdir -p /backup/$backup-label
duplicity /target file:///backup/$backup-label
```

(The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324541/referencing-a-dynamic-argument-in-the-docker-entrypoint) is maybe the more elegant solution for your use case. But this questions is slightly different, and the answer as well. So for reference. Also, as if your requirements should become more complicated...)