# Can we use "${a:-b}" for variable assignment in bash, with "a" a command?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script.

Per [this original post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts) I have learned that `c=${a:-b}` can be used to set the variable `c` if var `a` turns out to be unset or empty.

I wonder if we can extend this case into assigning the output of a command to a var. For example, I have a bash command `some command`, and I can assign it to the var `c` with

```
c=$(some command)
```

But I also want to include the case that if the output of `some command` is empty, I assign another default value to c.

I know that I can write vanilla `if-else` in the bash script, but just wonder if there's any more elegant way similar to `c=${a:-b}`?

Comment: `c=${a:=b}` would assign to both `a` and `c`, which might be a bit confusing to a reader. (I don't think the linked question had that either.) The one that doesn't assing to `a` is `c=${a:-b}`.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for pointing it out! have changed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In zsh, you can do:

```
var=${$(cmd):-default}
```

But in any POSIX-like shell including bash, you can always do:

```
var=$(cmd)
var=${var:-default}
```

Or

```
: "${var:=default}"
```

You do lose the exit status, but you could save it in a variable in between the two steps:

```
var=$(cmd)
exit_status=$?
: "${var:=default}"
```

You can also do things like:

```
var=$(cmd) exit_status=$? || var=default
```

For `$var` to be set to `default` if `cmd` failed (regardless of whether it output something or not).

Note that if `cmd` output is non-empty but consists only of newline characters, then after `var=$(cmd)`, `$var` will still be empty as command substitution strips *all* trailing newline characters. `bash` also strips all NUL characters. `zsh` preserves them, some other shells strip everything after the first NUL character. `yash` chokes on sequences of bytes not forming valid characters in the locale.

For `$var` to be set to `default` only if `cmd`'s output is non-empty, with GNU `grep` (or any implementation that can cope with (and not modify) non-text input, and doesn't ignore non-delimited lines), you can do:

```
var=$(cmd | grep '^') || var=default
```

where `grep '^'` returns true if it finds the beginning of at least one line in its input (and passes its whole input undisturbed to its output).

In that case, `cmd`'s exit status is lost. `$var` could end up being empty if `cmd` outputs only NULs or newlines.