# What is the name of this ENV definition ${HOME:-/home}?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I am creating a shell script to deploy a container, and found in some docker files this definition of ENV: `${HOME:-/home}`. I want to know what is the name of this kind of definition and where can I find more information about this kind of method.

Comment: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: [Parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122848/539768), does this help ?

Comment: Thank you very much to:
@glennjackman

Comment: Thank you very much to: @Marius_Couet