# update params of variable ksh88

Tags: linux, ksh

I'm trying to update a variable:

```
FLUX=first
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M`
justName=$FLUX
DIR_LOG=$REP_LOG_TD/DDL_TABLES_LOG/$justName'_'$DATE
if [ condition ]
then
 justName=other
 DIR_LOG=$DIR_LOG
fi
```

The variable is **DIR_LOG** and I want to update **justName** when **condition** is true.

The result that I want is

```
/root/log/DDL_TABLES_LOG/other_20181205_09_49
```

but I get

```
/root/log/DDL_TABLES_LOG/first_20181205_09_49
```

How to change the **justName** component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to defer variable expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/how-to-defer-variable-expansion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you break this down using `sh -x`, you'll see the problem:

```
+ FLUX=first
++ date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M
+ DATE=20181205_12_25
+ justName=first
+ DIR_LOG=/test/DDL_TABLES_LOG/first_20181205_12_25
+ '[' true ']'
+ justName=other
+ DIR_LOG=/test/DDL_TABLES_LOG/first_20181205_12_25
```

Note that the DIR_LOG variable is set before the condition is evaluated. Even when the condition evaluates to true, you'll get the same value for the DIR_LOG variable.

To change the behaviour, change the order of assignment as shown below:

```
FLUX=first
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M)
justName=$FLUX
if [ true ]
then
justName=other
fi
DIR_LOG=/test/DDL_TABLES_LOG/$justName'_'$DATE
```

Again, with `sh -x`:

```
+ FLUX=first
++ date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M
+ DATE=20181205_12_28
+ justName=first
+ '[' true ']'
+ justName=other
+ DIR_LOG=/test/DDL_TABLES_LOG/other_20181205_12_28
```

With this approach, you're setting the value of the justName variable first, before evaluating the DIR_LOG variable. This will get you the required output.

Note: The condition has been assumed to be true for convenience. When the condition fails, you'll see the output as shown below:

```
+ FLUX=first
++ date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M
+ DATE=20181205_12_32
+ justName=first
+ false
+ DIR_LOG=/test/DDL_TABLES_LOG/first_20181205_12_32
```